# Bulk recompiling edits to files by running external processes with a pool of 4 workers using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, child-process, asyncio

I am bulk recompiling edits to a c-like language which uses an external compiler.exe. The compiler takes the file paths as arguments and does the processing, nothing needs to be synchronized simply speed up the de/compilation of multiple files by using workers, when a worker finishes it should be recycled and the executable should be started again with the next set of arguments.

I was able to create some working code, but I believe there is a much more pythonic way to do this but I cant seem to find info on the right high level functions to Bulk start, await, and restart external processes with n workers while a generator is not exhausted.

I created a simple C# console app to simulate the compiler along with some fake files to be processed by the fake compiler. Can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhv99rgtmxudfiz/fake_files.zip?dl=1).

To run a test, create a folder to work out of, place the fake_files folder and the python script into your working folder, then run the script.

```csharp
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String InFile = args[0];
            String OutFile = args[1];
            Console.WriteLine($"Compiling file: {InFile}");
            Int32 ProcessingTime = new Random().Next(3, 25);
            Thread.Sleep(ProcessingTime * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Compiling complete! Outfile: {OutFile}");
        }
    }
}
```

```py
import asyncio
import functools
import logging
import string
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator

# create logger
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler('debug.log', mode='w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s]: %(message)s')

ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

log.addHandler(ch)
log.addHandler(fh)

SCRIPT_COMP_EXE = './fake_files/fake_compiler.exe'


async def signal_end_of_generator(complete_event: asyncio.Future):
    """This function waits for the tasks that are still compiling
    and is awaiting on the subprocess.run inside the executor.
    I did not see a built-in async way to do this, only sync with shutdown"""
    for t in asyncio.all_tasks():
        if t.get_coro().__name__ == 'recompile_script_async':
            await t

    complete_event.set_result(True)


async def recompile_script_async(file_generator: Generator,
                                 loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop,
                                 pool: ThreadPoolExecutor,
                                 complete_event: asyncio.Future,
                                 stop_iteration: asyncio.Event,
                                 worker: int):

    # Check file iterator
    try:
        fqp = next(file_generator)
    except StopIteration:
        if not stop_iteration.is_set():
            stop_iteration.set()
            loop.create_task(signal_end_of_generator(complete_event))
        return
    log.debug(f'Worker {worker}, has started.')

    # Compile
    outfile = Path(str(fqp).removesuffix('.c'))

    result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, functools.partial(
        subprocess.run,
        [SCRIPT_COMP_EXE, '-c', fqp, outfile],
        capture_output=True, text=False
    ))

    # Recycle Worker
    log.debug(f'Worker {worker}, has completed.')
    if not stop_iteration.is_set():
        log.debug(f'Recycling Worker {worker}.')
        loop.create_task(
            recompile_script_async(file_generator, loop, pool, complete_event, stop_iteration, worker))


def recompile_scripts_parallel(root, max_workers=4):
    log.info('Recompiling Scripts in parallel...')
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as pool:
        stop_iteration = asyncio.Event()
        complete_event = loop.create_future()
        file_generator = Path(root).rglob('*.bin.c')

        for worker in range(0, max_workers):
            log.debug(f'Starting parallel worker: {worker}')
            loop.create_task(
                recompile_script_async(file_generator, loop, pool, complete_event, stop_iteration, worker))

        loop.run_until_complete(complete_event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    recompile_scripts_parallel('./fake_files')
```

For example, the way that I use task recursion that starts a new task, and the way I safely await the processes once the generator is exhausted and the low level loop access just seems like a lot of low level code to achieve this.

Comment: Have you considered [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of `asyncio`?

Comment: The main reason I avoided ProcessPoolExecutor and multiprocessing was because it forked the entire python script and starts a new python interpreter. I am needing to await on the compiling process of external tools then continue one instance of the python script.

Comment: The other reason is most of the stuff in multiprocessing seems to be about message queues and synchronization of the multiple processes. I don't need the processes synchronized or to share any data, just need another instance to start up with the next set of data whenever one finishes. Using a set number of worker tasks that use recursion to start the next task was the best I could come up with. Ideally though there would be some high level api that takes a generator and a function, and keeps n number of workers alive while the generator gets processed.

Answer (score 1):

Combining `concurrent.futures` and `subprocess` libraries, seems to be the shortest sync way to achieve the same results. This spawns n number of threads that call subprocess.run which waits on the subprocess to finish. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` will automatically queue up any submited requests beyond its max_workers, only spawning as many as max_workers threads to work through the submited requests.

```
import logging
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(thread)s][%(levelname)s]: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)


def launch_compiler(file):
    outfile = Path(str(file).removesuffix('.c'))
    logging.info(f"Compiling: {file}")
    subprocess.run(['./fake_files/fake_compiler.exe', file, outfile], capture_output=True, text=False)
    logging.info(f"finished: {file}")


def compile_with_workers(max_workers):
    # When ThreadPoolExecutor is used as context-manager
    # .shutdown is called on exit which blocks until all background threads complete
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as pool:
        for fqp in Path('./fake_files').rglob('*.bin.c'):
            pool.submit(launch_compiler, fqp)

    # Execution will block until Executor completes all submitted requests
    logging.info('All processes finished.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    compile_with_workers(8)
```